# How to use tensorflow v2 with directml backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, amd-gpu

I have a computer with the windows operating system with an amd gpu (rx 5600 xt), and I want to run tensorflow on the gpu.
I found "tensorflow-directml" which allows me to run tensorflow on my gpu, but it uses tensorflow 1.14.0.
Is there another version of "tensorflow-directml" that uses tensorflow v2, or is there another way to run tensorflow in my gpu?

Thanks, and sorry if I wrote something wrong or inaccurate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has announced `DirectML-plugin` for `tensorflow 2` in June this year. Check it out at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-plugin. However I believe for your particular GPU model `DirectML-plugin` may not be compatible as of yet.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there another version of "tensorflow-directml" that uses tensorflow
> v2

No, According to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-directml/), latest release (i.e. on Sep 12, 2020) `tensorflow-directml 1.15.3.dev200911` is available for public. For more details please refer [this](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML#tensorflow-with-directml-preview).

**To run Tensorflow in GPU on windows**

For TensorFlow 1.x (i.e. for releases 1.15 and older, CPU and GPU packages are separate)

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15  # GPU
```

For Tensorflow 2.x (i.e. V2) onwards, pip package includes GPU support for CUDA enabled cards

```
pip install tensorflow
```

For more information please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#pip_package).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have an Amd GPU.
I will try to use it with Rocm on Ubuntu virtual machine.